# Save data from loop in txt file

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, save

I have a data frame **EEG**:

```
Description   Onset    Run
Neut_inc      3.7416   Run1
Neut_inc      4.3636   Run1
Reward        4.48     Run2
Neut_inc      5.7416   Run2
Neut_inc      6.72     Run3
Neut_inc      7.7416   Run3
Reward        8.96     Run3
```

My goal is to subset all *Neut_inc* conditions per run and save them in separate .txt files for each *Run*, so the .txt file after I read it in would look like this:

```
> Run1 
Description   Onset    Run
Neut_inc      6.72     Run3
Neut_inc      7.7416   Run3
```

I wrote a code that is looping through all runs, however it saves .txt file only with the last run.

```
for(run_number in unique(EEG$Run)){
    run <- subset(EEG[which(EEG$Run == run_number),])
    Neut_con <- subset(run[which(run$Run == run_number),], Description %in% c("Neut_con"))  

write.table(Neut_con, file ="C:/Users/EXPERIMENTS/onsets/Neut_con.txt",row.names=FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")  

}
```

How should I change the code?

Comment: I don't see a `}` at the end of that `for` loop.

Comment: I forgot it. There is a }

Answer (score 1):

```
for(run_number in unique(EEG$Run)){
    run <- subset(EEG[which(EEG$Run == run_number),])
    Neut_con <- subset(run[which(run$Run == run_number),], Description %in% c("Neut_con"))  

    write.table(Neut_con, file =paste0("C:/Users/EXPERIMENTS/onsets/Neut_con_", run_number, ".txt"),row.names=FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")  

}
```

The problem is you are writing one file and then overwriting it every time you go through the loop. By adding the paste0() function, you make the file name dynamic so that you have file1, file2, file3, et cetera. This way you don't overwrite the file each time.